# Why is parallel R code not faster on machine with more cores?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I have lenovo w540 64 bit windows 7, 16 gb ram, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600M CPU @ 2.90 GHz running 64 bit R 3.2.2

I also have a pc with 64 bit windows 7, 16 gb ram, Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2620 v3 @ 2.40 GHz (processors)

I have a function that I run in parallel. On my 4-core laptop I ran the following code

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)

cores=detectCores()
cl <- makeCluster(cores[1]-1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)

#Initialize variables
partsOrder <- list()
numSim <- 10

#start clock
start <- proc.time()

SimResults <- foreach(j=1:100) %dopar%{
  RobotSimulation()
}

#stop using all cores
stopCluster(cl)

#stop the clock
end <- proc.time()-start
end[3]
```

What I dont understand is that on my 4 core laptop it takes 30 mins to do 100 iterations. On my 24 core laptop it takes the same amount of time. I can see all 24 cores being used in the task manager though and there are 24 R processes running. Does it matter to R if the cores are logical or physical?

EDIT: added RobotSimulation() code and some sample data

```
partsList <- data.frame(JobNum = sample(c('a','b','c','d'),4000,replace=TRUE)
,DS.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C1.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C2.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C3.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C4.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C5D5.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C6D6.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C5D7.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C6D8.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
,C7CD.CT = sample.int(10,4000,replace=TRUE)
)

RobotSimulation <- function(){

#randomize the dataset of parts and record the order
parts <- partsList[sample(nrow(partsList)),]
partsOrder <- list(parts$JobNum)

#choose a random sample of parts to populate the conveyor belts
#this random assignment will be constant across all iterations of the simulation
set.seed(101)
LineParts <- parts[sample(nrow(parts),234,replace=FALSE),]

#pass parts through system one at a time and record cycle times at each dip
LineParts_dfList <- lapply(seq(nrow(parts)), function(i){      
    #Index line
    LinePartsTemp <- parts[1,]
    LinePartsTemp[2:nrow(LineParts),] <- LineParts[1:nrow(LineParts)-1,]

    #put new part into system
    LinePartsTemp[1,] <- parts[i,]

    #update the list of parts on the line
    LineParts <<- LinePartsTemp      
})

#combine the results of passing all parts through the system
LinePartsAll <- do.call(rbind, LineParts_dfList)

#find the cycle times at each robot for each time a new part went through
otherstations_veclist <- 
  list(
    DS = LinePartsAll[seq(1,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'DS.CT'],
    D1 = LinePartsAll[seq(10,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C1.CT'],
    D2 = LinePartsAll[seq(26,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C2.CT'],
    D3 = LinePartsAll[seq(42,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C3.CT'],
    D4 = LinePartsAll[seq(57,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C4.CT'],
    D5 = LinePartsAll[seq(85,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C5D5.CT'],
    D6 = LinePartsAll[seq(120,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C6D6.CT'],
    D7 = LinePartsAll[seq(167,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C5D7.CT'],
    D8 = LinePartsAll[seq(210,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C6D8.CT'],
    D9 = LinePartsAll[seq(216,nrow(LinePartsAll), by=234),'C7CD.CT']
  )

#record results
result <- list(partsOrder = partsOrder, CT = otherstations_veclist)
return(result)
}
```

Comment: There's a certain amount of overhead when using multiple cores in order to start them up and recombine the objects. Have you tried running the simulation more times in each iteration and reducing the iterations?

Comment: With a windows machine you might want to look into Microsoft R. I haven't used it, but they claim that it is specifically designed to better exploit multicore machines. I don't know how true those claims are, but it can't hurt to check them out: https://mran.microsoft.com/documents/rro/multithread/

Comment: I am starting the clock after the cluster is set up so the overhead is not part of the time.

Comment: could you show the function `RobotSimulation` so that we can take look for more details?

Comment: I added my code for RobotSimulation and some example data. Thanks for taking a look.